# PDF FOOTER PROBLEM

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have problem with footer as you can see on picture. Whole pdf page's margin is set 5mm left, 5 mm right 5 mm bot. Is it possible just to overwrite this margins and to move this footer like on image,5mm left, 5mm right and 5mm bot, but other pages must be same like i set at first. Can someone help me?[image]

Comment: You'll probably get better help if you [edit] your post to include your markup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Igor: For such scenarios, I usually prefer to remove margins at page level and introduce margins for required sections for e.g.

**Page**

```
<apex:page>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        @page{
            margin: 0px;
        }

    </style>
    <!-- HTML -->

    ...
    <div style="margin-left: 5mm; margin-right: 5mm">
        <!-- Page body -->
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You don't have to `@mention` the OP...

Comment: It is not guaranteed that CSS will work as expected, because Salesforce uses ancient PDF engine and it can ignore some CSS rules.

Comment: Yes Salesforce does not support all CSS rules, you have to try different combination of CSS to get the desired result.

Comment: But if say:
@page{

    margin: 0px;
}

It will do for whole page...

Comment: Yes using margin : 0px will definitely stretch to whole page. But then you can control the specific sections say content section to keep desired margin, whereas header and footer can be rendered with no margins, as I mentioned in my response above.